# D3 javascript Difference between foreach and each

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What is the difference between `forEach` and `each` in D3js?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

First, `.forEach()` is not part of d3, it's a native function of javascript arrays. So,

```
["a", "b", "c"].forEach(function(d, i) { console.log(d + " " + i); });
// Outputs:
a 0
b 1
c 2
```

And that works even if d3 is not loaded on the page.

Next, d3's `.each()` works on d3 selections (what you get when you `d3.selectAll(...)`). Technically, you can call `.forEach()` on a d3 selection, since behind the scenes, a d3 selection is an array with extra functions (one of them is `.each()`). But you shouldn't do that because:

1. Doing so will not produce the desired behavior. Knowing how to use `.forEach()` with a d3 selection in order to produce any desired behavior would require intimate understanding of the inner workings of d3. So why do it, if you can just use the documented, public part of the API.
2. When you call `.each(function(d, i) { })` on a d3 selection, you get more than just `d` and `i`: the function gets invoked such that the `this` keyword anywhere inside that function points to the HTML DOM element associated with `d`. In other words `console.log(this)` from inside `function(d,i) {}` will log something like `<div class="foo"></div>` or whatever html element it is. And that's useful, because then you can call function on this `this` object in order change its CSS properties, contents or whatever. Usually, you use d3 to set these properties, as in `d3.select(this).style('color', '#c33');`.

The main takeaway is that, using `.each()` you get access to 3 things you need: `d`, `this` and `i`. With `.forEach()`, on an array (like in the example from the beginning) you only get 2 things (`d` and `i`), and you'd have to do a bunch of work to also associate an HTML element with those 2 things. And that, among other things, is how d3 is useful.

Comment: Thanks for writing a great answer, and for doing it without including any of the unnecessary snark that's so common on SO...

Comment: There should be a caveat here: when you do need different scoping for 'this' keyword but you don't need datum in your called function, selection[0].forEach(...) is much more convenient than selection.each, which necessitates a 'self = this' workaround in parent function if 'this' is meaningful outside of merely referencing DOM elements.

Comment: @sdupton scoping for `this` is a concern in many d3 scenarios where you pass in higher order functions, including for example `selection.style("color", function(d,i) { /* here 'this' is a DOM element */  })`. I believe that's partially why d3 classes (like `d3.svg.axis` for example) don't use the `prototype` methods of defining classes — as a way to avoid reliance on `this`.  But I don't see how `selection[0].forEach(...)` avoids this issue. Isn't it the same problem?

Comment: @meetamit you can explicitly scope 'this' for use in Array.prototype.forEach with a second argument, passed after the function to be called on each element.  When you are writing anything resembling an object-oriented wrapper (I'm using ES6 classes), losing explicit scoping of 'this' can be a bummer.

Comment: @sdupton, cool — I didn't know `.forEach` accepted a 2nd param for scoping `this`. It made me realize that you could use something similar-ish for achieving the same effect with d3's `.each()` by using javascript's `.bind()` method. For example, the following will scope `this` to `window` and will console.log it: `selection.each(function() { console.log(this); }.bind(window))`.

Comment: Any idea on how to break an each loop?

Comment: @Gerard It's not possible. See [the implementation of `each`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/v3.5.14/d3.js#L964-L971). There's no opportunity to break.